# Alternate sum of square of series sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let

$S_{n}=-1^2-2^2-3^3+4^2+5^2+6^2-7^2-8^2-9^2+\cdots \cdots +a_{n}\;\;(n\; \text{terms})$

Then which one is right

$(a)\;\; S_{100}>S_{99}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\; S_{99}>S_{98}\;$

$ (c)\; a_{100}+a_{36}=a_{64}\;\;\;\; (d)\; 2a_{100}-S_{100}=4850$

what i try

let $$S_{n}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^{4k+1}\bigg[k^2+(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2\bigg]$$

How do i solve it help me please

Comment: Why $4k+1$ ? Why $k,k+1,k+2$ ? Why does $k$ run from $0$ to $n$ when $S_n$ is deemed to have $n$ terms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Obviously, the sign of the term $a_n$ depends on $(n-1)\bmod6$ (as the period is $6$), and can be expressed as

$$(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{(n-1)\bmod6}3\right\rfloor+1}.$$

Hence $a_{99}=-99^2$ and $a_{100}=100^2$. This answers $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Then $a_{36}=36^2$ and $a_{64}=64^2$ allow to check $(c)$.

$(d)$ seems harder. Grouping the terms by six, we have

$$-(6k-5)^2-(6k-4)^2-(6k-3)^2+(6k-2)^2+(6k-1)^2+(6k)^2=108k-45$$

so that $S_{102}=108\dfrac{17\cdot18}2-45\cdot17$, and you backtrack to $S_{100}$.